# Как заполнить ключи вложенного словаря, если они находятся в одной колонке Excel файла?

Tags: python, pandas, dict

Как можно заполнить ключи вложенного словаря данными из `excel` файла, если они находятся в одной колонке, есть условное разделение, но когда пытаюсь загрузить ключи, то во вложенные ключи загружается вся колонка, а нужно, чтобы загружались ключи согласно соответствию условному разделению

Вот мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

dict1 = dict()
a = pd.ExcelFile("D:/Excel_PZ_py/test.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(a)
df_c = df.copy()
df_c = df_c.fillna(0)
key_df_c = df_c[df_c['S'] == 0]
key_df_c = key_df_c.loc[key_df_c['name'] != 'text']
key1 = key_df_c['name'].values
for i in key1:
    dict1[i] = dict()
    dict_v = dict1[i]
    for t in df_c['name']:
        dict_v[t] = []
```

Вот файл `excel` с условным разделением:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

желаемый вид словаря :

{'A': {5:[], 8:[], 9:[], 3:[], 7:[]}, 'B':{19:[], 16:[], 18:[], 15:[]}, 'C':{26:[], 22:[]}}

Upd:
Ссылка на исходный файл excel:
https://easyupload.io/dp6q6g

Comment: может быть, вы выложите свой примерный файл с данными?

Comment: @strawdog, добавил

Comment: а теперь уточните желаемый результат. либо у вас не хватает закрывающих скобок, либо я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: @strawdog, прошу прощения, не заметил ошибку, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, я не совсем понял вопрос, но то, что я понял, можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("1.xlsx").dropna(subset=["name"])
df = df[df["name"]!="text"]
df["key"] = df["name"]
df.loc[df["name"].str.isalpha()!=True, "name"] = pd.NA
df["name"] = df["name"].fillna(method="ffill")

d = df.dropna().groupby("name")["key"].apply(list).to_dict()
res = {k:[{x:[]} for x in d[k]] for k in d.keys()}
```

res:

```
{'A': [{5: []}, {8: []}, {9: []}, {3: []}, {7: []}], 'B': [{19: []}, {16: []}, {18: []}, {15: []}], 'C': [{26: []}, {22: []}]}
```

**Update:**

вероятно, автору вопроса нужен такой результат:

```
res1 = {k:{x:[] for x in d[k]} for k in d.keys()}
```

res1:

```
{'A': {5: [], 8: [], 9: [], 3: [], 7: []}, 'B': {19: [], 16: [], 18: [], 15: []}, 'C': {26: [], 22: []}}
```

Comment: А что делать, если не только буквенные названия условных обозначений, а в перемешку, например A1a и т.д.?

Comment: `df.loc[df["name"].str.isdecimal()==True, "name"] = pd.NA` - можно попробовать так.